# Finding the determinant of a $ k \times k$ matrix (Hessian matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

Given $H(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3}) = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \newline \frac{1}{2} & -2 & 0 \newline 0 & 0 & -4 \end{bmatrix}$, I want to find (I think) the leading principle minors.

So for instance $H_{1}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) = -2$, and $H_{2}(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}) = 4 - \frac{1}{4} = \frac{15}{4}$ (I think).

If these are correct so far then what would $H_{3}(x_{1}, x_{2}, x_{3})$ be? Above I am just taking determinants. It might make sense if I say that I am trying to determine the convexity from this Hessian matrix.

Comment: you may get the determinant using the last row ( or last columne) and in this way it's quite simple: $-4\cdot (-2\cdot -2-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{1}{2})=-15$

Answer (score 0):

Convexity requires the Hessian to be positive semidefinite. A matrix with a negative diagonal entry cannot be positive semidefinite; so you can forget convexity already. But maybe it's concave? One way to check is to reverse the sign of the matrix and apply the convexity criterion to the new matrix. Or you can work with the matrix as is and check that $(-1)^k\det H_k> 0$ for $k=1,2,3$.

Which is indeed the case. To find $H_3$, it's best to follows the suggestion made by  [Jorge Alexis Castillo Seplveda](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/652816/finding-the-determinant-of-a-k-times-k-matrix-hessian-matrix#comment1374771_652816): expand along the last row. Since all but one entries of this row are zero, you'll  see that $H_3=-4H_2$, which finishes the computation.